# Run sen2cor for a single tile (granule)

Tags: sentinel-2, sen2cor

The `L2A_Process` script provided by sen2cor expects a full product directory in the `.SAFE` format. Is there any way to use it for a single tile (a subdirectory in the `GRANULES` folder)?

If no, is there any conceptual reason preventing it from being implemented this way? As far as I understand, sen2cor in any case processes each tile within the given product on an independent basis.

What I am trying to do is to build and maintain an archive of L2A imagery for a limited area of interest, and I do not want to spend the processor cycles on the tiles that do not overlap with the AOI.

Answer (score 0):

Sen2cor uses several bands to calculate a cloud mask, which is used in its atmospheric correction process. It also uses DEM and atmospheric parameters obtained for an entire area (based on MGRS grid).